# Debugging Chef recipes on target VM?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm using Chef to provision new virtual machines. I've used chef-zero to test the recipes in local mode on a Chef development server.

When i run the recipe against a new VM is there a way to see the output from the Chef recipe commands? I don't have access to the CHEF server (other than write access to publish new updates to the cookbook).

Does Chef log output anywhere on the target CM?

Comment: Indeed, by default it logs to stdout unless you configure a location in [client.rb](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_client.html)

Comment: On the target VM where shud I look to find this output, chef runs the recipe behind the scenes once the gm is provisioned

Comment: modify `/etc/chef/client.rb`, and set the `log_level` to `:debug` and the `log_location` to `/path/to/log/file`, and only then run `chef-client`. then you can fetch the log file. also you might want to consider [`chef-shell`](https://docs.chef.io/chef_shell.html)